# where do I put the image directory in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I do not know where is the directory to put the images in to make the background of the game I am making
please help!

this is the code...

> ```
> from tkinter import*
> import random
> import time
>
>
> class Game:
>     def __init__(self):
>
>         self.tk = Tk()
>         self.tk.title("Mr. Stick Man Races for the Exit")
>         self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
>         self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
>         self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500, height=500, \
>                              highlightthickness=0)
>         self.canvas.pack()
>         self.tk.update()
>         self.canvas_height = 500
>         self.canvas_width = 500
>         self.bg = PhotoImage(file="backround.gif")
>         w = self.bg.width()
>         h = self.bg.height()
>         for x in range(0, 5):
>             for y in range(0, 5):
>                 self.canvas.create_image(x * w, y * h, \
>                                          image=self.bg, anchor='nw')
>         self.sprites = []
>         self.Running = True
>  
>     def mainloop(self):
>         while 1:
>             if self.Running == True:
>                 for sprite in self.sprites:
>                     sprite.move()
>             self.tk.update_idletasks()
>             time.sleep(0.01)
>             
> g = Game()
> g.mainloop()
> ```

and this is the error I get...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Mr.Stickman Races To The Exit!.py", line 37, in <module>
    g = Game()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Mr.Stickman Races To The Exit!.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.bg = PhotoImage(file="backround.gif")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4063, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4008, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "backround.gif": no such file or directory
```

i have put the background image in the tkinter library but the same error shows up
I hope someone can help me on this
Thanks

Comment: Put it in the same directory as the script

Comment: Probably because you misspelled "background".

Comment: @Novel yup , that is also high probability

Comment: if you put the image in the same directory as this script, you could get its path by first importing `from pathlib import Path` and then `Path("abc").resolve().parent/"background.png"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put image in Tkinter Library 
Bring the picture to your script folder
[image: Place the image here]

**Make sure your filename is same with the program**